# r - get list items according a names vector without loop

Tags: r

i have a list:

```
x = 1:5
y = 6:10
z = 11:15
u = 16:20
tlist = list('X' = z, 'Y' = y, 'Z' = z, 'U' = u)
names_vect = c('X', 'Y')
```

Is there any way to get sublist of 'X' and 'Y' according `names_vect` without using loop?
Thanks.

Comment: do you mean `tlist[c('X','Y')]` ?

Comment: or `tlist[names_vect]`

Comment: You mean sapply(names_vect, function(element) tlist[[element]])  ?

Comment: or you may use `tlist[names_vect]`, if you store element names in that vector. Edit: _scoa was faster..._

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I've tryed `tlist[[c('X','Y')]]`, saddly.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you want to use `tlist[names_vect]` not `tlist[[names_vect]]` - note the single square brackets.

Single square brackets extracts a sublist; double extracts an element. Since you want two elements then double doesn't make sense in this situation.